# How to upload file size > 2GB using fsharp.data

Tags: f#, f#-data

I followed this [document](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html) for handling multipart form data

I can upload ok with file size below 2GB. With the size is greater than 2GB, the application sends nothing.

Does anyone have experience in uploading large files using fsharp.data?